# Bug in a code the buttons the buttons do absolutely nothing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem that I do not know which is a bug, when I press the add photo button or the send button does not happen at all and I do not get any error,
The first button should open my photos, and the second should send to a RecyclerView in a fragament I give my code

Sorry for my english use the google translate

the fragment

```
 public class PostCreateDialog  extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 1;
    private Post mPost;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ImageView mPostImageView;
    private View mRootView;
    private Uri mSelectedUri;
    private ImageButton sendPostButton;
    private ImageButton selectFotoButton;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        mPost = new Post();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mRootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_post_dialog, null);

        mPostImageView = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_display);
        selectFotoButton = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview);
        sendPostButton = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview);
        builder.setView(mRootView);
        return builder.create();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview:
                selectImage();
                break;
            case R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview:
                sendPost();
                break;
        }
    }


    private void sendPost() {

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Sending post...");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();

        FirebaseUtils.getUserRef(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".",",")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                final String postId = FirebaseUtils.getUid();
                TextView  postDialogText = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_edittext);
                String text = postDialogText.getText().toString();

                mPost.setUser(user);
                mPost.setNumOfLikes(0);
                mPost.setNumOfComments(0);
                mPost.setNumOfUnlikes(0);
                mPost.setTimeOfcreation(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mPost.setPostText(text);

                if(mSelectedUri != null){
                  FirebaseUtils.getImageRef().child(mSelectedUri.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(mSelectedUri).addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                          String url = Contants.POST_IMAGES + "/" + mSelectedUri.getLastPathSegment();
                          mPost.setImageUrl(url);
                          addToMyPostList(postId);

                      }
                  });
                }else {
                    addToMyPostList(postId);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



    }

    // ESTE DE AQUI ES COMO UN FINAL A TOODO SI SE COMPLETA O SI CANCELA
    private void addToMyPostList(String postId){
         FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postId).setValue(mPost);
        FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postId).setValue(true).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                dismiss();
            }
        });

    }


    // ESTOS DOS METODOS SIRVEN PARA SELECCIONAR LA IMAGEN
    private void selectImage() {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent1.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Comlete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
              mSelectedUri = data.getData();
                mPostImageView.setImageURI(mSelectedUri);
            }
        }
    }


     }
```

the dialog:

```
 public class PostCreateDialog  extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 1;
    private Post mPost;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ImageView mPostImageView;
    private View mRootView;
    private Uri mSelectedUri;
    private ImageButton sendPostButton;
    private ImageButton selectFotoButton;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        mPost = new Post();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mRootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_post_dialog, null);

        mPostImageView = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_display);
        selectFotoButton = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview);
        sendPostButton = (ImageButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview);
        builder.setView(mRootView);
        return builder.create();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview:
                selectImage();
                break;
            case R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview:
                sendPost();
                break;
        }
    }


    private void sendPost() {

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Sending post...");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();

        FirebaseUtils.getUserRef(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".",",")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                final String postId = FirebaseUtils.getUid();
                TextView  postDialogText = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_edittext);
                String text = postDialogText.getText().toString();

                mPost.setUser(user);
                mPost.setNumOfLikes(0);
                mPost.setNumOfComments(0);
                mPost.setNumOfUnlikes(0);
                mPost.setTimeOfcreation(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mPost.setPostText(text);

                if(mSelectedUri != null){
                  FirebaseUtils.getImageRef().child(mSelectedUri.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(mSelectedUri).addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                          String url = Contants.POST_IMAGES + "/" + mSelectedUri.getLastPathSegment();
                          mPost.setImageUrl(url);
                          addToMyPostList(postId);

                      }
                  });
                }else {
                    addToMyPostList(postId);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



    }

    // ESTE DE AQUI ES COMO UN FINAL A TOODO SI SE COMPLETA O SI CANCELA
    private void addToMyPostList(String postId){
         FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postId).setValue(mPost);
        FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postId).setValue(true).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                dismiss();
            }
        });

    }


    // ESTOS DOS METODOS SIRVEN PARA SELECCIONAR LA IMAGEN
    private void selectImage() {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent1.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Comlete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
              mSelectedUri = data.getData();
                mPostImageView.setImageURI(mSelectedUri);
            }
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: You haven't called `setOnClickListener(this)` on any of the `Button`s.

Comment: No setOnClickLisnter() is used in the code

Comment: @dskato, simply add this to your code where you have initialised widget.

mPostImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
selectFotoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
sendPostButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to display any toast on button click.
If toast appears then your click event is working and if the toast is not shown then your button click is not working.